# Regex - Magento Magmi Import: How to rename image files correctly?

Tags: regex, magento-1.7, magmi

Magmi is an import tool for some eCommerce software.

I am trying to import images.  The problem is that my images are all named "SKU.jpg" and are located in different directories.

Magmi has a tool to solve this using regex.

My problem is coming up with the correct regex expression to make this work.

Note: I have tested my import with manually renamed files, and it works perfectly.

Magmi says if you have similar image names in different directories like this:

```
thumbs/01.png
standard/01.png
```

Then use this regex:

```
re::(.*)/(.*)\.(.*)$::$2_$1.$3
```

And the files will be renamed like so:

```
01_thumbs.png
01_standard.png
```

Now, my files are structured like so:

```
/images/Headshot/Rectangle/VT08.jpg
/images/FloorShot/Rectangle/VT08.jpg
```

I was assuming that this regex would work:

```
re::/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)\.(.*)$::$2_$4.$5
```

to change files like so:

```
Headshot_VT08.jpg
```

However, that is not the case.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: I am trying to find that out now.  Apparently there is a debug mode so I will see if that helps.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to find the output. I was wondering if the first character being a `/` was the problem, but everything I have tried has not worked.

Comment: Have you tried temporarily structuring your files like they suggest? If so did their regex work?

Comment: Well it seems like their Regex does not work either.  Hmm, there must be a silly mistake somewhere because Magmi hasn't let me down yet.  Thanks for your help.  I will be looking into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
re::/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*)$::$2_$4
```

no need to separate last one since you'll only want to prefix filename, so you can keep it in a single capture

the ? at the end of the capture is non-greedy (ie: stop capture at first match)

i'll fix the wiki sample since with only one / , the problem didn't arise but the sequence is not easily repeatable.

Comment: For the record I have not yet tried this since I had already renamed my image files using Bulk Rename Utility and everything worked fine like that. I will try this on my next set of product imports.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
 /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/(.*)\.(.*)  
 so re::/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/(.*)\.(.*)$::$2_$4.$5
```

The / at the front is fine, the problem is the (.*)/ part this will match as much as it can so it will match /images/Headshot/Rectangle/ instead of just the first bit.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work.  I do think it would work however, I think something is wrong with the interface.